# EJS can't find image in static public folder

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying render a html template as a PDF using EJS, however the images are not appearing.
My project structure:

```
 - public
   - images
       image.jpg
 - routes
     documentsRoute.js
 - services
     documentsService.js
 - views
     document-template.ejs
 server.js
```

I am setting the public folder as a static folder in my server.js like so:

```
...
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
...
```

In my template file I'm using this as my src for the image

```
<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="my_image">
```

I'm rendering the file from my document service like so:

```
ejs.renderFile('views/document-template.ejs', inputs, (err, data) => {
            if (err){
                throw err;
            }

            let options = {
                "format": "A4",
                "header": {
                    "height": "20mm"
                },
                "footer": {
                    "height": "20mm"
                }
            };

            pdf.create(data, options).toFile('test.pdf', (err, res) => {
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
            });
        })
```

The rest of the template is rendered correctly, just not the image, instead it shows the alt text. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the view directory correctly in your server file.
So instead of `app.use(express.static('public'))`
try

```
app.use(express.static( path.join(__dirname, './public')))
```

Comment: Just tried this and it still hadn't worked unfortunately

Comment: Could You add link to the repo  please ?

Answer (score 0):

it's rather `pdf` having trouble with the path. try using absolute path

add full path in the `base` property of `pdf` options:

```
let options = {
    "format": "A4",
    //...
    base: `${req.protocol}://${req.headers.host}`
};
```